# javascript client for local SQLite on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I'm familiar with SQLite from having worked with it using the System.Data.SQLite provider for .NET and also Adobe AIR using ActionScript. I've been asked to investigate what is involved in creating offline data-driven apps for mobile devices (iPhone+iPad and Android for now, maybe Blackberry). The database would have to be available locally on the device because users would often be in rural areas with very unreliable and spotty cellphone reception.

Will the same javascript codebase run unchanged on iDevices and Android devices? Or will separate versions be required for each mobile OS? I see [the W3 has discontinued the standards process](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#transaction-steps) for local web SQL database(s) because there's only one SQL contender at present and it takes at least two to tango.  Is the webkit javscript SQL API in a state of flux?

Answer (score 0):

**Hello Tim**,

When developing database centric applications for Android and IPhone, you are not locked in to using Sqlite. There is another alternative, which in many cases might be even better; namely CouchDB.

In both cases there are solutions available which makes it easy to develop database centric applications for Android and IPhone using the same code.

**CouchDB**

CouchDB, although written in Erlang, is basically a JSON based database using javaScript as its default interface. CouchDB can be extremely fast. However, CouchDB is not a relational database.

License: Apache license, 2.0.

Official site: http://couchdb.apache.org/

CouchDB for Android: https://github.com/couchbase/Android-Couchbase

CouchDB for IPhone: http://www.macworld.com/article/159606/2011/05/couchbase.html

**Sqlite**

PhoneGap is the choice if you prefer working with Sqlite. Using PhoneGap you can use the same javaScript code for both IPhone and Android for communication with Sqlite, and simply replace the middleware to match the OS you are compiling.

For Android the middleware is *phonegap-version.jar*, whereas for IPhone the file is named *phonegap-version.dmg*.

In addition to Android and IPhone, PhoneGap makes it possible to port the same applications to Blackberry, WebOS, Symbian and Bada.

License: BSD/MIT.

Official site: http://www.phonegap.com

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is the only option when developing HTML5 Web Apps (if I understood you correctly).

You can check information about IndexedDB, which is already implemented in WebKit (Chrome 12) as window.webkitIndexedDB and also [Firefox has implemented it.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/IndexedDB)